# How to handle out of order Zookeeper notifications?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, distributed, apache-curator

I have multiple processes operating on an in-memory queue. That queue is a manifestation of sequential znodes created/deleted at Zookeeper.

When a znode is added, an equivalent item is added to the queue at all the involved processes. And also when a znode is removed, the equivalent item is removed from the queue at every involved process.

The addition and removal signals are expected to be balanced because every added item should eventually be removed.

I faced a situation when a znode was added and removed very quickly and the removal notification was received at one of the processes before the addition notificaiton. So an attempt to remove that item occurred but failed because it wasn't actually there, and then the addition signal was received which added the item but then it was never removed.

A simple solution would be to assert the existence of the equivalent znode after adding the item to the queue and that's good enough for me now but it doesn't seem as efficient as it can get.

My question is if there is a way to handle this scenario in a more efficient or "zookeeper way"?

Comment: "A simple solution would be to assert the existence of the equivalent znode after adding the item to the queue and that's good enough for me now but it doesn't seem as efficient as it can get." - you must do this actually. It's the only way to ensure the scenario you describe.

Comment: Another idea is to keep the item but with a special flag if the removal signal didn't find the item. So when the addition signal is received, it will be ignored if it finds the flagged item. This seems like it'll need some safeguards such as JVM synchronization (i.e. not using ZK) and considerable testing as not to drop a valid addition signal.

Comment: Do you happen to use znode watches for the notification process?

Comment: Sure. The problem is about the order of these notifications.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use ZooKeeper as a message queue which is not designed for. There's no ordering neither delivery guarantee in ZooKeeper for watcher notifications.
Instead you should use some messaging system like Kafka or RabbitMQ for this use case.